# I am virtualizing Debian 9 on a Vmware 6.0. Time is going nuts

Tags: debian, esxi

I am using Debian 9 (64) with a german keyboard.
tzselect EUROPE/Berlin

local time now is 10:28

Debian date says: 03:28:30 CST 2019

I have switched off the "hardware" timesetting from the vmware host.

I use a local NTP server

kind regards,

Bodo

Comment: Supposedly you have to change the idea of the OS of whether the (emulated) BIOS maintains its time in your local timezone, and not in UTC. See [`hwclock(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/8/hwclock) for more info. Basically, Debian installers default that setting to UTC, but Microsoft® Windows™ default it to LOCAL, and hence most virtualizing software assumes just that and pretends the H/W clock on the "machine" contains time in the local TZ. Look for "adjtime file" in that manual page.

Comment: Also see [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime#Hardware_clock_and_system_time_when_dual_booting).

Comment: I decided to install server with german settings and ask english speaking users to set their LANGUAGE from de_DE.UTF-8 to en_US.utf8